# Magnific Popup и Slick Slider в нем

Tags: slick.js, popup, magnific

Использую скрипт Magnific Popup и в открывшемся ajax окне пытаюсь разместить slick slider. Получается или popup окно без галереи slick slider http://nt.no-yandex.ru/tt.php (по кнопке открывается), или же незаконченный, но рабочий вариант галереи  http://nt.no-yandex.ru/include/gal.php , но в новой вкладке, а не в popup окне.

Понимаю, читал, что как-то надо инициализировать внутри magnific popup галерею, пробовал через callbacks, через parseAjax внутри запуска magnific popup, но вообще ничего не получается. Возможно не так инициализирую. Может есть на пальцах готовый пример такой реализации?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.popup-content').magnificPopup({
    callbacks: {
        open: function() {
            $('.slider-galler .list').slick({
                autoplay: false,
                autoplaySpeed: 4000,
                speed: 1000,
                arrows: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```